# managed property is returning null

Tags: java

I am trying to inject a a managed bean into another managed bean (I need to take an action in one managed bean only if the user is loggen in, and that user is saved on the other managed bean). But is returning NULL! Each managed bean links to a different XHTML page, so maybe a new HTTP session is created?

The first managed bean:

```
@Named(value = "travellerLoginManagedBean" )
@SessionScoped
public class travellerLoginManagedBean implements Serializable {

@EJB
private travellerUserEntityFacadeLocal travellerUserEntityFacade;

private String userName;
private String password;
private Boolean loggedIn;
/**
 * Creates a new instance of travellerLoginManagedBean
 */
public travellerLoginManagedBean() {
}

public Boolean getLoggedIn() {
    return loggedIn;
}

public void setLoggedIn(Boolean loggedIn) {
    this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Boolean validUser(){
    loggedIn=true;
    return travellerUserEntityFacade.checkLogin(this.userName, this.password)==true;
}

public String login() {
    if (validUser()==true){
        return "/travellerHome.xhtml";
    }else{
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Usuario y/o password incorrecto!"));
        return "/travellerLogin.xhtml";
    }

}

}
```

The second managed bean:

```
@Named(value = "travellerSearchFlightsManagedBean")
@RequestScoped
public class travellerSearchFlightsManagedBean{


@EJB
private itineraryTravellerFacadeLocal itineraryTravellerFacade;

@EJB
private itineraryFacadeLocal itineraryFacade;

@ManagedProperty(value="#{travellerLoginManagedBean}")
private travellerLoginManagedBean loginBean;
private String departureLocation;
private String arrivalLocation;
private Date departureDate;
private int departureHour;
private int departureMinute;
private int numPassengers;
private int maxStops;
private String economyOrBusiness;
private ArrayList<itineraryDTO> itinerariesList;
private ArrayList<itineraryTraveller> searchList;
private itineraryTraveller selectedItinerary;
private String stopPrint;
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(travellerSearchFlightsManagedBean.class.getName());

 ( ......)

public void reserveFlight(){
    if (loginBean.getLoggedIn()==true){
        System.out.println("iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiin");
        //status reserved when traveller reserves an itinerary
        selectedItinerary.setStatus('r');
        //set the userName from the user who reserved this itinerary before persist it in a shared among all users db
        selectedItinerary.setUserName(loginBean.getUserName());
        //persist the reserved itinerary in the db
        itineraryTravellerFacade.create(selectedItinerary);
    }else{
        System.out.println("not     iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiin");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Must be logged in before reserving an itinerary"));
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to work, a Bean injection needs to:

- Add the `@ManagedProperty` annotation (which you did)
- Add the reference of the other Bean in the `faces-config.xml` file.

An example of `faces-config.xml` from [Apache Documentation](https://myfaces.apache.org/wiki/core/user-guide/jsf-and-myfaces-howtos/backend/accessing-one-managed-bean-from-another.html) should clarify:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>neededBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>fqn.to.NeededBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

<managed-bean>
    <managed-beaenter code heren-name>usingBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>fqn.to.UsingBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
     <property-name>neededBean</property-name>
     <value>#{neededBean}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

In your specific case:

- `NeededBean` = `travellerLoginManagedBean`
- `UsingBean` = `travellerSearchFlightsManagedBean`

---

The Apache Documentation also states that the only constraint to use a Bean injection are:

- the using bean must have scope which is the same as or shorter than the needed bean
- the using bean must have a property-setter method which takes the needed bean as a parameter
- the beans cannot have managed dependencies on each other.

---

If you need more information, take a look at [Apache Documentation](https://myfaces.apache.org/wiki/core/user-guide/jsf-and-myfaces-howtos/backend/accessing-one-managed-bean-from-another.html).

PS: I noted that you write class names with a lowercase letter, but with Java code convention (CamelCase) every class name should start with an uppercase.

Comment: but I dont have a facesconfig file in my WEBINF FOLDER!!! btw thanks for your answer

Comment: ok i created the faces config file with what you said. But still returns null the managed property. and it should not be null

Comment: I know. It is usually a problem of names (try to shorten the class names doing a refactor). I also heard of people that solved this error simply cleaning the project. Try to do both.